# Blog is not indexing in google search

Tags: google, google-search, blog, search-engine-indexing, search

I have a blog with url http://webzpedia.blogspot.in which is about 2 years old. In early days there is 200+ pageviews coming from the google search itself. But from last 4-5 months, google stopped indexing my blog in its search results. Can anyone answer why this happening?

Comment: What do you mean by "stop indexing my blog"?

Comment: @Zistolen: It looks like the site has been completely de-indexed by Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your site appears to have been completely dropped from Google's index. `site:webzpedia.blogspot.in` returns no results in Google search.

Looking at your site, it appears to be nothing but a website directory where site owners can submit their site for inclusion (without using `rel="nofollow"`), there is otherwise no unique content in itself. This is probably why you have been de-indexed by Google.

Answer (score 1):

You have posted a lot less in 2012 than in the previous years. A lot less. 572 posts in 2011 and only 5 in 2012. 4 of those in January. The answer you're looking for may be laying there.

Comment: This would certainly account for a slowing down of the Googlebot, however, it seems the entire site has been removed from Googles index. (I think the nature of the site is a problem.)

Comment: @w3d I definitely agree with your answer.